# Install Asterisk on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, communication

I'm new to the Raspberry Pi and I hope to start a project which will need Asterisk and Raspbian OS both installed on the same SD card.

**What I want**

I need to run Asterisk and Raspbian OS both at the same time. Simply speaking I need to access Asterisk functions and do particular things using Python which is installed in the Raspbian OS.

Ex: Access incoming call's caller ID and do particular things using Python.

**What I Did**

I downloaded RasPBX image and installed it on my SD card, but it doesn't provide me a way of accessing Raspbian OS like installing Raspbian OS using NOOBS.

**Problem**

So is there a way I can use Asterisk installed on Raspbian OS? Can I access Asterisk functions in the Raspbian OS GUI, without any inconvenience?

Comment: Have you considered using 2 Pi's?

Comment: @SteveRobillard I didn't think about that. Is that necessary? I mean can't I run both in same RPi?

Comment: It might help if you explained what your project is and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I want to get caller ID of incoming call and search that in database which has phone numbers stored. And if it matches to the one of numbers stored in database, it will direct that call to softphone using WiFi.

Comment: I assume you have already looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104488/freepbx-transfer-incoming-call-to-destination-based-on-database-result

Comment: @SteveRobillard What I'm trying to do is convert PSTN call to VoIP using OBi110 and direct that through WiFi to a softphone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62961/discussion-between-user9125-and-steve-robillard).

Comment: Raspbx has root access...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to start of would be to use RasPBX

http://www.raspberry-asterisk.org/

It is a Raspbian Jessie base OS with Asterisk and FreePBX installed and preconfiugred with all the goodies. (Trust me, the pre confiugraion of all these applciations takes allot of time)

Since it is Debian OS, you can install Python on it (probably is already installed) and write your scripts as you need.

To use Raspbian just SSH into it with the WebGUI password. If you want root you may need to enable it by using `passwd root`

[There is more information here at the documentation](http://www.raspberry-asterisk.org/documentation/)

Comment: Thank you. As Ive mentioned I did download RasPBX image and did install it into my RPi SD card. But I get an command line interface. I dont know and couldnt find a way to use RasPBX with GUI. Any help?

Comment: You need to log in using SSH, just like you would do with any other headless linux system. Or connect a monitor, screen and keyboard and log in using that way

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I did logged into Web GUI. but unfortunately I couldnt find Python installed or a way to install python using web GUI. any help sir?

Comment: I managed to install PIXEL on OS and get a GUI. So now it is easy to install Python. Thank you.